# ByteArray Property Too Large to send within putExtra("obj", obj) of intent when opening another Activity

Tags: android

I have an Object that has string, int, double, byte[], properties. My byte[] is storing an image from the database as i store the images in byte inside my tables.

The problem is that when i serialize the object and pass the object through intent.puteExtra("obj", obj) the app crashes without any errors in the console.

I then made my byte[] property = byte[1] and all worked the activity swithed and the data passes through the intent.

Here is my  Sell Obj:

```
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class Sell extends Product implements Serializable
{
public byte[] Image1;
public byte[] Image1a;

public byte[] Image2;
public byte[] Image3;
public byte[] Image4;
public String postcode;
public double postage;
public int isDelivered ;





public Sell(int p_Id, String p_u_id, double price, String title, String description, int category, String tags,
            byte[] image1, byte[] image2, byte[] image3, byte[] image4
            , String postcode, double postage, int isDelivered, String date, int type)
{

    super(p_Id, p_u_id,price,title,description,category,tags, type, date);
    this.Image1 = image1;
    this.Image2 = image2;
    this.Image3 = image3;
    this.Image4 = image4;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.postage = postage;
    this.isDelivered = isDelivered;


}

}
```

Here is my Product Obj:

```
package com.asianretail.trikam.asianretail;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Product implements Serializable {

public  int p_Id;
public String P_U_Id;
public double Price;
public int Category;
public String Tags;
public String Title;
public String Description;
public int Type;
public String Date;

public Product(int p_Id, String p_u_id, double price, String title, String description, int category, String tags, int type, String date)
{

    this.Date = date;
    this.p_Id = p_Id;
    this.P_U_Id = p_u_id;
    this.Price = price;
    this.Title = title;
    this.Description = description;
    this.Category = category;
    this.Tags = tags;
    this.Type = type;

}
}
```

To start the activity from the fragment i use this:

```
Product prod = null;
                                for(int i = 0; i < pObj.size(); i++){
                                    if(((Product)pObj.get(i)).p_Id == ((int)v.getTag())){
                                        prod = (Product)pObj.get(i);
                                    }
                                }
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putSerializable("valueProd", prod);

                                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("bundleProd", bundle);
                                startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to write byte array to a file and pass the url of the file to bundle instead. You should not pass the image in bundle as it may try to access more memory than allocated in case your byte array too large.

Comment: I guess ur right. But because I have implemented so much with storing the images. I'm just going to pass the I'd of the product and then load the data in the new activity that way. Thanks for ur response